# SQL Loader : which one is the default delimiter for stream record format in Control File?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Here is my Control File

```
  load data
 infile ’sample3.dat’ “str ‘”
 into table example
 fields terminated by ‘,’ optionally enclosed by ‘"’
 (item char(10),
 destination char(2))
```

Can anyone tell me the default delimiter in the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The record delimiter is \n by default, you can change it like in the following example:

```
load data  
infile ’sample3.dat’ “str ‘*\n”  
into table example  
fields terminated by ‘,’ optionally enclosed by ‘"’  
(item char(10),  destination char(2))
```

In this case, the record delimiter in *\n so your data could look like:

```
Item 1,London*
Item 2,Multi
line*
```